# res.redirect creating another request on the same route

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication, loopback

This is my first time here, so I hope I post this correctly.

I am working with Loopback here, and I am having a problem when I try to redirect to another route.
Basically I have two middlewares. The first, checks with Firebase if the user if authenticated and allowed to visit /dashboard. If no, I call the next() middleware and this one redirects back to /login again.

Dashboard.js:

```
'use strict';
    const firebase = require("firebase");
    exports.dashboard = (req, res, next) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            console.log("Before render: "+res.headersSent); // false
            res.render("dashboard", {photoUrl: user.photoURL, displayName: user.displayName, email: user.email });
            console.log("after render: "+res.headersSent);
          } else {
            // console.log("on else"  );
            next()
          }
      });
    
    };
    
    exports.notLogged = (req, res) => {
      console.log("no one logged in");
      res.redirect('/login');
    };
```

Route on server.js:

```
 app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.dashboard, dashboard.notLogged);
```

The middleware on login.js:

```
exports.login = (req, res) => res.render("login")
```

And its route:

```
app.get('/login', login.login);
```

For example, if I try to access "/dashboard" and I am not logged, the "console.log("no one logged in"); " will be twice on the console, or any other log on the flow. It looks like another request was made, but I can't understand why or how. If I remove the redirect and simply end the response or render a page, the problem does not occur.

Thank you! :)

**UPDATE**

I am back here and still with no solution. This is driving me crazy.

[image: Double GET happening after res.redirect :(]

Answer (score 2):

You might used the middleware in a wrong way.

```
 app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.dashboard, dashboard.notLogged);
```

This line means after running dashboard.dashboard, dashboard.notLogged will be running anyway, whether or not you are calling next()

So you can solve the problem like this:

```
     if (user) {
        console.log("Before render: "+res.headersSent); // false
        res.render("dashboard", {photoUrl: user.photoURL, displayName: user.displayName, email: user.email });
        console.log("after render: "+res.headersSent);
      } else {
        // console.log("on else"  );
        notLogged()
      }
```

And remove notLogged from here:

```
 app.get('/dashboard', dashboard.dashboard)
```

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Comment: This is not correct. If you are building middleware chains, they are invoked sequentially and only if the previous middleware is calling `next()`.

Comment: Yes, that's in fact wrong. This way the response gets stuck in the "else" and nothing happens. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I tried like this:

In the else:

`notLogged(req, res);`

And the middleware:

`function notLogged(req, res) {
  console.log("no one logged in");
  res.status(200);
  res.redirect('/login');
  res.end()
}

exports.notLogged = notLogged;
`

This works as well, but did not fix the problem :/